# How to Identify multiple null values from json in iOS

Tags: ios, json

I am identifying when one value is null, but how to identify all the multiple null values in a single code in iOS.

This is the code that I am using to identify null element in JSON Data :
  NSString *longitude = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"shape"];

```
    if ([longitude isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Shape Description is NUll");
    }
    else
    {
        shapeLabel = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"shape"];
    }
    NSString *clrrr = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"color"];

    if ([clrrr isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Color Description is NUll");
    }
    else
    {
        clr = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"color"];
    }
    NSString *lotiddd = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"lotId"];

    if ([lotiddd isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Lotid Description is NUll");
    }
    else
    {
        lotId = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"lotId"];

    }
```

I don't want to use multiple Strings to identify individual null values.
Is there any way to identify all null values in Single code from JSON ? Need some guidance on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `JSON` data consists of strings alone, you may use categories.

Create a category say `NotNullNil` on `NSString`. You will then get two files `NSString+NotNullNil.h` and `NSString+NotNullNil.m`.

In `NSString+NotNullNil.h` declare a class method on `NSString` that you are going to use for null check on strings.

Write :

```
+ (NSString *)notNullString:(NSString *)string;
```

Then define that method in `NSString+NotNullNil.m` as follows:

```
+ (NSString *)notNullString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (string == (id)[NSNull null] || string == nil || string == NULL)
    {
        return @"";
    }
    return string;
}
```

You may then use it like:

```
shapeLabel = [NSString notNullString:[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"shape"]];
```

**PS:** Don't forget to import `NSString+NotNullNil.h` wherever you want to use it. i.e. use:

```
#import "NSString+NotNullNil.h"
```

You may also create similar category methods for classes that you use often.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you have to create a category first. Create a new category on "NSString" and name it "NotNullNil".

Comment: there is no default method for `NSString` class called `notNullString`. Thats why you are getting that error.

Comment: declare this method in your new `"NSString+NotNullNil.h"` file. like `"+ (NSString *)notNullString:(NSString *)string;"`

Comment: Then define it in the ".m" file like in the answer.

Comment: Try this awesome [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/45942/intro-object-oriented-design-part-2), if you have any doubts regarding categories. Feel free to ask for doubts. :)

Comment: i already define that method in h file but it also gives error i use Shape label In  (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary { if(self = [self init]) { } } – this method

Comment: Can you Provide me Full Description of it ??

Comment: Please check updated answer. You are getting the error maybe because you are not importing the category. please try that.

Comment: Thanks A Lot Its Totally Working ...i done That !! Thanks A lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no **Single code from json** . *You need to iterate through the dictionary by using the `allKeys`. Use the condition for null with the key*

```
NSArray*keys=[jsonDict allKeys];
for(NSString* key in keys){
if ([[jsonDict valueForKey:key]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
      NSLog(@"%@ Key is null ", key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Loop through the keys of your Dictionnary

```
for(id key in jsonDictionary){

    if ([[jsonDictionary valueForKey:key]  isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Value is of type NSNull for key: %@",key);
    }
}
```